# Incrementing a character in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to make a Caesar Cipher program, where the user enters a string, and the characters in that string are incremented to 3 alphabets, so A becomes D, and so on using basic stuff.

I cannot increment the character i in character array letters[i] as it is a foreach iteration. I also tried using for loop, as follows, but I can't seem to get it right. Initially, I got a singular output like a "d", but now it crashes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Caesarian Cipher program");
  Console.WriteLine("Please, enter a word.");

  string word = Console.ReadLine();

  char[] letters = word.ToCharArray(); //chops the string up into individual characters.

// USING FOR LOOP

for(int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
{
  i += 3;
  Console.WriteLine(letters[i]);
}

//USING FOREACH LOOP

  foreach(char i in letters)
  {     
     i +=3;                         // supposed to shift the alphabet by 3 steps.
     Console.WriteLine(i);          //prints the alphabet after every loop iteration.
  } 
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: what if 'Z' is used in the input word?

Comment: @Coder1991, the question is not about `Caesar Cipher`, it is about `Incrementing a character in a foreach loop`. So it is not matter.

Comment: @RAM yes I agree. It seems OP wants to increment the letter to an Alphabet. If 'z' is available in the input it becomes '}' which is not an alphabet.

Comment: If it had to be THAT specific, well, no. In that case, then Z would be incremented back to A. Only 26 letters.

Comment: @Coder1991, Yes I know. But it is not the problem in this question. DDGamer83 dose not know how he should increase the char code. What he should do to prevent mistakes for `x` , `y` and `z` need some conditions in his code that he did not write a question about it. So I give him **[an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483385/incrementing-a-character-in-a-foreach-loop/#48483464)** that addresses his question.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code snippet

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Caesarian Cipher program");
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter a word.");

    string word = Console.ReadLine();

    char[] letters = word.ToCharArray(); //chops the string up into individual characters.

    // USING FOR LOOP
    int shift=3;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
    {
        // Letter.
        char letter = word[i];
        // Add shift to all.
        letter = (char)(letter + shift);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }

    //USING FOREACH LOOP



}
```

using foreach

```
foreach (var c in letters)
    {

        // Add shift to all.
        char letter = (char)(c + shift);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **`Increment a character in a foreach loop`** so I answered to it. You should change the code to implement the algorithm (*It should be your challenge*).

**[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfzX34)**

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Caesarian Cipher program");
      Console.WriteLine("Please, enter a word.");
    
      string word = Console.ReadLine();
    
      char[] letters = word.ToCharArray(); //chops the string up into individual characters.
     
      // For            
      for(int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
      {
            var charAsInt=(int)letters[i];
            var newChar= (char)(charAsInt+3);
            
            Console.Write(newChar);
      }
      
      Console.WriteLine();

      // ForEach            
      foreach(char letter in letters)
      {
          var charAsInt=(int)letter;
          var newChar= (char)(charAsInt+3);
            
          Console.Write(newChar);
      }
    }
}
```

**Output** (with `abcd` input):

> Welcome to the Caesarian Cipher program
>
> Please, enter a word.
>
> abcd
>
> defg
>
> ---
>
> defg

Answer (score 1):

In this approach we define the alphabet that is covered by our Caesar shift rule. This allows the algorithm to safely accommodate lowercase, uppercase, numeric, and other characters, as long as you add them to the alphabet (otherwise you are just relying on ASCII ordering which is a bit trivial).

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public string CaesarShift(this string input, int offset)
    {
        const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        return new string
        (
            input.Select 
            (
                c =>
                { 
                    var index = alphabet.IndexOf(c);
                    return index == -1 
                        ? c
                        : alphabet[(index + offset + alphabet.Length) % alphabet.Length];
                }

            ).ToArray()
        );
    }
}

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var word = "THE QUICK RED FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY BROWN DOG. the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog. 123456789!(*&#*";

        var encoded = word.CaesarShift(3);
        Console.WriteLine(encoded);

        var decoded = encoded.CaesarShift(-3);
        Console.WriteLine(decoded);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
WKH TXLFN UHG IRa MXPSV RYHU WKH ODcb EURZQ GRJ. wkh txlfn uhg ir0 mxpsv ryhu wkh od21 eurzq grj. 456789ABC!(*&#*
THE QUICK RED FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY BROWN DOG. the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog. 123456789!(*&#*
```

[Run the code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5yzXJl)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Caesarian Cipher program");
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter a word.");

    string cypher = String.Join("", Console.ReadLine().Select(x => (char)(((x - 'a' + 3) % 26) + 'a')));
    Console.WriteLine(cypher);
}
```